first mechanic details are stored correctly but rest mechanic details of type checkbox is storing 0's in datatbase
The form has dynamic section called mechanic details. The first mechanic details are stored correctly but rest mechanic details of type checkbox is storing 0's in datatbase.
my html code
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WPG Tool</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script>
        function addMechanic() {
            const mechanicContainer = document.getElementById('mechanicContainer');
            const newMechanicDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newMechanicDiv.classList.add('mechanic');
            const mechanicIndex = document.getElementsByClassName('mechanic').length;

            const mechanicName = document.createElement('textarea');
            mechanicName.name = `mechanic_name[${mechanicIndex}]`;
            mechanicName.placeholder = 'Enter mechanic';

            const variableHeading = document.createElement('h4');
            variableHeading.innerText = 'Select game mechanic variables:';

            const variableRanges = ['Strategy', 'Skill', 'Chance_Luck', 'Knowledge'];
            const variableRangeDiv = document.createElement('div');
            variableRanges.forEach(range => {
                const label = document.createElement('label');
                const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
                checkbox.name = `mechanic_variable_${range}[${mechanicIndex}]`;
                label.appendChild(checkbox);
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` ${range.replace('_', '/')}`));
                variableRangeDiv.appendChild(label);
            });

            const typeHeading = document.createElement('h4');
            typeHeading.innerText = 'Select game mechanic type:';

            const typeRanges = ['Learning_Mechanic', 'Game_Mechanic', 'Both'];
            const typeRangeDiv = document.createElement('div');
            typeRanges.forEach(range => {
                const label = document.createElement('label');
                const radio = document.createElement('input');
                radio.type = 'radio';
                radio.name = `mechanic_type[${mechanicIndex}]`;
                radio.value = range;
                label.appendChild(radio);
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` ${range.replace('_', ' ')}`));
                typeRangeDiv.appendChild(label);
            });

            const knowledgeHeading = document.createElement('h4');
            knowledgeHeading.innerText = 'Type of Knowledge involved in learning mechanic:(choose only for learning mechanic)';

            const knowledgeRanges = ['Factual_Knowledge', 'Conceptual_Knowledge', 'Procedural_Knowledge', 'Meta-Cognitive_Knowledge'];
            const knowledgeRangeDiv = document.createElement('div');
            knowledgeRanges.forEach(range => {
                const label = document.createElement('label');
                const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
                checkbox.name = `mechanic_knowledge_${range}[${mechanicIndex}]`;
                label.appendChild(checkbox);
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` ${range.replace('_', ' ')}`));
                knowledgeRangeDiv.appendChild(label);
            });


            const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
            removeButton.type = 'button';
            removeButton.innerText = 'Remove';
            removeButton.onclick = () => mechanicContainer.removeChild(newMechanicDiv);

            newMechanicDiv.appendChild(mechanicName);
            newMechanicDiv.appendChild(variableHeading);
            newMechanicDiv.appendChild(variableRangeDiv);
            newMechanicDiv.appendChild(typeHeading);
            newMechanicDiv.appendChild(typeRangeDiv);
            newMechanicDiv.appendChild(knowledgeHeading);
            newMechanicDiv.appendChild(knowledgeRangeDiv);
            newMechanicDiv.appendChild(removeButton);
            mechanicContainer.appendChild(newMechanicDiv);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="submit.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Participant Details</legend>
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Game Details</legend>
            <label for="game_name">Game Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="game_name" name="game_name" required><br><br>
            <label for="educational_content">Educational Content:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="educational_content" name="educational_content" required><br><br>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Analysis</legend>
            <p>Play the game once before analysing the game to understand the rules and gameflow.</p>
            <p>Use the analysis tool while playing the game.</p>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Formulation</legend>
                <br>
                <label for="setup">Select the setup from the below options:</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup1" name="setup[]" value="setup1">
                <label for="setup1">Placing tokens at the 0th state of the game. Example: Ludo, Snake and Ladders</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup2" name="setup[]" value="setup2">
                <label for="setup2">Distribution of different 0th game states. Example: Scrabble, Galaxy Raiders</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup3" name="setup[]" value="setup3">
                <label for="setup3">Distribution of resources. Example: Monopoly</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup4" name="setup[]" value="setup4">
                <label for="setup4">Hidden winning state setup. Example: Master Mind, Battleship</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup5" name="setup[]" value="setup5">
                <label for="setup5">Role distribution. Example: Bagh Chal, Cricket</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup6" name="setup[]" value="setup6">
                <label for="setup6">Divided space setup. Example: Tennis</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup7" name="setup[]" value="setup7">
                <label for="setup7">No space setup. Example: Lakshadweep</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup8" name="setup[]" value="setup8">
                <label for="setup8">No setup. Example: Candy Crush</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="setup9" name="setup[]" value="setup9">
                <label for="setup9">Other <input type="text" id="other_setup" name="other_setup"></label><br>
                <br><br>
                <label for="gameplay_space">Gameplay Space</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="space1" name="space" value="space1" required>
                <label for="space1">Separate space to play. Example: Tennis, Battleship</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="space2" name="space" value="space2" required>
                <label for="space2">Common/same space to play. Example: Chess, Xing</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="space3" name="space" value="space3" required>
                <label for="space3">Combination (both separate and common space to play). Example: Scrabble, Galaxy Raiders</label><br>
                <br><br>
                <label for="gameplay_action">Gameplay Action</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="action1" name="action" value="action1">
                <label for="action1">Separate time to act (turn by turn or sequence gameplay)</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="action2" name="action" value="action2">
                <label for="action2">Same time or no time to act (Simultaneous gameplay)</label><br>
                <br><br>
                <label for="end_condition">Gameplay End Condition:</label><br>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="end_condition" name="end_condition" required></textarea>
                <br><br>
                <label for="winning_condition">Gameplay Winning Condition:</label><br>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="winning_condition" name="winning_condition" required></textarea>
                <br><br>
                <label for="end_analysis">End condition analysis</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="end1" name="end" value="end1">
                <label for="end1">The game ends with the resources (Coins, tiles, overs, etc) Ex: Cricket, Carroms</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="end2" name="end" value="end2">
                <label for="end2">The game ends with time. Ex: Candy Crush</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="end3" name="end" value="end3">
                <label for="end3">The game ends with a winner. Ex: Chess</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="end4" name="end" value="end4">
                <label for="end4">The game ends when all the players finish. Ex: Ludo, Uno</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="end5" name="end" value="end5">
                <label for="end5">The game ends when the last player remains. Ex: Musical chairs</label><br>
                <br><br>
                <label for="winning_analysis">Winning condition analysis</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="win1" name="win" value="win1">
                <label for="win1">The winner is the player with the highest score, points, etc.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="win2" name="win" value="win2">
                <label for="win2">The winner is the player who achieves the winning state.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="win3" name="win" value="win3">
                <label for="win3">The winner is the player who remains till the end.</label><br>
                <br><br>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Formulation</legend>
            <br>
            <label for="mechanics_analysis">Break down the planning you do to apply mechanics</label><br>
            <h2>Mechanic Details</h2>
            <div id="mechanicContainer">
                <div class="mechanic">
                    <textarea name="mechanic_name[0]" placeholder="Enter mechanic"></textarea>
                    <h4>Select game mechanic variables:</h4>
                    <div>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mechanic_variable_strategy[0]"> Strategy</label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mechanic_variable_skill[0]"> Skill</label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mechanic_variable_chance_luck[0]"> Chance/Luck</label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mechanic_variable_knowledge[0]"> Knowledge</label>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Select game mechanic type:</h4>
                    <div>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="mechanic_type[0]" value="learning_mechanic"> Learning Mechanic</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="mechanic_type[0]" value="game_mechanic"> Game Mechanic</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="mechanic_type[0]" value="both"> Both</label>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Type of Knowledge involved in learning mechanic:(choose only for learning mechanic)</h4>
                    <div>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mechanic_knowledge_factual[0]"> Factual Knowledge</label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mechanic_knowledge_conceptual[0]"> Conceptual Knowledge</label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mechanic_knowledge_procedural[0]"> Procedural Knowledge</label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mechanic_knowledge_meta_cognitive[0]"> Meta-Cognitive Knowledge</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <button type="button" onclick="removeMechanic(this)">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="addMechanic()">Add Mechanic</button><br><br>

            <h4>Relation between time, gameplay and learning</h4>
                    <div>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="mechanic_time1" value="no_time"> No time to plan.</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="mechanic_time1" value="gameplay"> Have time to plan but only related to gameplay.</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="mechanic_time1" value="learn"> Have time to plan but only related to knowledge.</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="mechanic_time1" value="both"> Have time to plan related to knowledge and gameplay.</label>
                    </div>
                    
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>`

the result is
Mechanic 0 Variables: Name: a, Strategy: 1, Skill: 0, Chance/Luck: 0, Knowledge: 0, Type: learning_mechanic
Factual: 1, Conceptual: 0, Procedural: 0, Meta-Cognitive: 0
Mechanic 1 Variables: Name: b, Strategy: 0, Skill: 0, Chance/Luck: 0, Knowledge: 0, Type: Learning_Mechanic
Factual: 0, Conceptual: 0, Procedural: 0, Meta-Cognitive: 0
Mechanic 1 variables is taking 0's even if selected skill and conceptual variables
My php code
`<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "game_analysis";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Insert participant details
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$game_name = $_POST['game_name'];
$educational_content = $_POST['educational_content'];
$end_condition = $_POST['end_condition'];
$winning_condition = $_POST['winning_condition'];
$setup = isset($_POST['setup']) ? implode(", ", $_POST['setup']) : '';
$space = $_POST['space'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$win = $_POST['win'];
$mechanic_time1 = $_POST['mechanic_time1'];

// Insert into participants table
$sql = "INSERT INTO participants (name, email, game_name, educational_content, end_condition, winning_condition, setup, space, action, end, win, mechanic_time1)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$game_name', '$educational_content', '$end_condition', '$winning_condition', '$setup', '$space', '$action', '$end', '$win', '$mechanic_time1')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $participant_id = $conn->insert_id;

    // Prepare statement for mechanics insertion
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mechanics (participant_id, mechanic_name, strategy, skill, chance_luck, knowledge, mechanic_type, factual, conceptual, procedural, meta_cognitive) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    foreach ($_POST['mechanic_name'] as $index => $mechanic_name) {
        // Initialize all variables
        $strategy = isset($_POST['mechanic_variable_strategy'][$index]) ? 1 : 0;
        $skill = isset($_POST['mechanic_variable_skill'][$index]) ? 1 : 0;
        $chance_luck = isset($_POST['mechanic_variable_chance_luck'][$index]) ? 1 : 0;
        $knowledge = isset($_POST['mechanic_variable_knowledge'][$index]) ? 1 : 0;
        $mechanic_type = isset($_POST['mechanic_type'][$index]) ? $_POST['mechanic_type'][$index] : '';
        $factual = isset($_POST['mechanic_knowledge_factual'][$index]) ? 1 : 0;
        $conceptual = isset($_POST['mechanic_knowledge_conceptual'][$index]) ? 1 : 0;
        $procedural = isset($_POST['mechanic_knowledge_procedural'][$index]) ? 1 : 0;
        $meta_cognitive = isset($_POST['mechanic_knowledge_meta_cognitive'][$index]) ? 1 : 0;

        // Debugging: Print the variables for the current mechanic
        echo "<pre>Mechanic $index Variables: ";
        echo "Name: $mechanic_name, Strategy: $strategy, Skill: $skill, Chance/Luck: $chance_luck, Knowledge: $knowledge, Type: $mechanic_type\n";
        echo "Factual: $factual, Conceptual: $conceptual, Procedural: $procedural, Meta-Cognitive: $meta_cognitive\n";
        echo "</pre>";

        // Bind parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("isiiiiiiiii", $participant_id, $mechanic_name, $strategy, $skill, $chance_luck, $knowledge, $mechanic_type, $factual, $conceptual, $procedural, $meta_cognitive);

        // Execute and check for errors
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Error inserting mechanic $index: " . $stmt->error . "<br>";
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();


    echo "Record added successfully";
    


} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

`


You have no assigned values to some of the checkboxes and why do you use prepared statements for some inserts but not the other?
